# how to get sorted json array data from Firebase in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, sorting, firebase-realtime-database

I am new firebase and swift. I have an issue to sort data in firebase in swift.

This is my Firebase data:
[image: Firebase screenshot]

I need to get descend sorted data from firebase like following format.

```
[{
    "category: "test",
    "created_at"; "12345678",
    ... ... ...
 },
 {
    ... ... ...
 },
 {
    ... ... ...
 }]
```

I have used following code:

```
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        self.dataDic = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]
        print(self.dataDic)
    })
```

But it returns following format json data.

```
[ "-Lghl96MdaB3f-x6FBoO": {
    "category" = "",
    "created_at" = 1559840989982,
    "earning" = 234,
    ... ... ...
}, 
 "-LghlOwAkmMxFRC6kGFd": {
      ... ... ...
}, "-LghxXW-mCbxAImqA3Ro": {
    ... ... ...
}]
```

How to get only child values json array? And also how to sorte by "visit_count"?

Please advance me if anyone knows this issue. Thanks

Comment: There's a few things to address. First is the code provided in the question reads everything in the *denmarkpostapp* which could be a large amount of data Secondly, nothing in your code does any kind of ordering - they are just read in order by their key. Another issue is that Firebase doesn't offer a descending order - however, it can be easily done but you need to decide if you want to do it in code (if data is limited) or let Firebase do it. See [Working With Lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data). Update your code with more info an we'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Understand for no offering descending order. And could u provide detail code to get json data from firebase? Thanks

Comment: Sure. The link I included in my above comment is the guide that shows specifically how to read lists of data from Firebase.

Comment: Yes. I saw it. But I want to get json array only contain datas. I have posted that json format. But I can get entire json array, that is contain firebase auto id. How to get json data array without firebase auto id?

Comment: Nothing in your question is an array. There's a root node, it's child nodes (parents) and then child nodes under each parent. It appears your parent node keys were created with .childByAutoId which is good. Take another look at the docs as it details how to read in a single or a list of nodes. Generally, when you read a firebase node, that node is read along with the child nodes it contains - and that's a typical pattern. For example if you read in a series of nodes, you may want to edit some child node. You would need to know the parent key to then write that data back out.